# Boost converter, why the voltage derates when frequency rises?

Tags: dc-dc-converter, frequency, boost, mosfet-driver, powermosfet

I am simulating a boost converter in ltspice.

[image: This is the circuit]

vin=3V, vout_bst=12V, ideal inductor, capacitor, diode and voltage source.
When I use an ideal switch, raising the frequency doesn't affect the output voltage but when I use MOSFET transistor BSZ036NE2LS the voltage drops when I raise the frequency.

[image]

*The highest is @100kHz, the lowest @1MHz (100kHz steps)

I understand the transistor causes it but I didn't find a frequency restriction in it's datasheet and I don't know how to explain this derating.

edit: Rload=17.142 (I wanted for the simulation Iload=0.7A)

Comment: Have you tried adding a load resistor on the output? Basic boost conversion needs a load and feedback system to control duty cycle in order to regulate the output voltage.

Comment: Yeah it doesn't look like there's any feedback.  With a real mosfet, switching losses increase when you increase frequency so that could be a factor.  The graph makes me think of a really primitive feedback circuit I use sometimes because of the overshoots, but my circuit would burn out a mosfet if it had to to maintain the same voltage even if you did something stupid with frequency, so there must be a difference in how we decide more or less.  I just charge and discharge a cap and the voltage on the cap sets my duty cycle.  You don't mention what range your sample frequencies are at either.

Comment: Real devices take a finite time to switch and have various parasitics like capacitance. This might explain your observation.

Comment: Thank you for the responses.
About Rload, it's about 17 Ohms (I made and edit)
and ok I get that there are switching losses. I would like to calculate somehow and how they are mathematically related to the frequency. I want to show a calculation that shows what is the maximal frequency that I can work with, but I can't find the way...

Comment: What is your gate driver circuit?

Comment: it's an pwm generator based on an ideal 555 timer
ON voltage 3V, OFF voltage 0V